# Linux allocates memory at specific physical address

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, device-driver, pci

I am testing a PCI Endpoint driver, I would like to do simple copy from the PCI RootPort side to the PCI Endpoint side. In PCI Endpoint side, we have address translation from PCI address to CPU physical address. We can configure the CPU physical address in the translation so that it maps to the specific DRAM region. The problem is how can we allocate a memory buffer at that specific CPU physical address to make sure the write from RootPort side really works?

Any recommendations are appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the translation from PCI address to CPU physical address fixed at boot time, or can it be changed on the fly by your code? The

Comment: Hi @Adrian Cox, we can change it on the fly. The configuration are just register settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can remap the translation on the fly, then you should work like any driver that uses DMA. Your basic reference for this is [Chapter 15 of LDD3](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch15.pdf), plus the [Linux DMA API](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/DMA-API.txt).

What you are allocating is a DMA coherent buffer, via `dma_alloc_coherent`. On most platforms you should be able to pass in a null `struct device` pointer and get a generic DMA address. This will give you both a kernel virtual address to access the data, and a dma address which is the CPU physical address to map through your translation layer.

If your address translation is not very flexible, you may need to modify the platform code for your endpoint to reserve this buffer early on, in order to meet address alignment requirements. This is a bit more complicated, but there is an [update of the bigphysarea](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1273100) patch to recent kernels that may help as a starting point.

Comment: Hi Adrian Cox and @gby, Thank you very much for your answer. Both reserved 1MB from kernel command line and DMA allocation works fine. Choose Cox's answer as the best solution because he reached the solution first. Thank both of you again!

Answer (score 3):

You need to first reserve the physical memory area. The easiest but ugly way to do that is to pass a "mem=" parameter to the kernel command line that precludes the physical memory range you are interested in from kernel memory management and then use [ioremap](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-9-sect-4)() to get a virtual mapping of that.

For example if your machine has 256 Mb of RAM use mem=255M to reserve the last Mb to your uses and then map it via ioermap()

NOTE: original answer fixed based on feedback from @Adrian Cox.

Comment: Isn't that back to front? `ioremap` gives you a virtual address to access an IO resource, but @dien wants to allocate RAM within a particular translation window.

Comment: Hi @gby, thank you for your answer! If we ioremap the a portion of the ram region, how can we make sure that we do not mess up with other kernel/application data?