# How to allocate buffer memory at physical address in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to create a char device driver which can write a buffer at specific physical address(e.g.0x1000-0000). Can someone please help.

Here is a sample of the driver program which I have written.

//include files

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
```

//device name
    #define test_NAME   "test"

```
//need to store this memory at a physical location
static char device_memory[100];
```

//open function

```
int test_open (struct inode *my_inode, struct file *my_file)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Inside the test_open function...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

//close device function

```
int test_close (struct inode *my_inode, struct file *my_file)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Inside the test_close function...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

//read function

```
ssize_t test_read (struct file *my_file, char __user *userbuff, size_t 
nRead, loff_t *nReadOffset)
{
    int notCopied;

    notCopied = copy_to_user(userbuff, device_memory, nRead);
    printk("Inside the test_read function...\n");
    return (nRead - notCopied);
}
```

//write function

```
ssize_t test_write (struct file *my_file, const char __user *userbuff, 
size_t nWrite, loff_t *nWriteOffset)
{
    int notCopied;

    notCopied = copy_from_user(device_memory, userbuff, nWrite);
    printk("Inside the test_write function...\n");
    return (nWrite - notCopied);
}

static struct file_operations test_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = test_open,
    .release = test_close,
    .read = test_read,
    .write = test_write,
};

int init_module(void)
{
    int retval;
    retval = register_chrdev(120, test_NAME, &test_fops);
    if (retval != 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Failed to register test driver...\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO "test registration succeeded...\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    unregister_chrdev(120, test_NAME);
    printk(KERN_INFO "test unregistered successfully...\n");
    return;
}


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("SK110");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Driver for a test (virtual) device.");
```

Comment: @jww Added code sample. Please suggest how to store memory at physical address.

Comment: Refer to gby's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136135/linux-allocates-memory-at-specific-physical-address) question